# How to change json in array in forEach loop ? JS

Tags: javascript

I need to change JSON.

Example of my JSON array:

```js
{
    // ...any properties
    point: [
      location: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0 
      },
      name: "Point1",
      pointId: 1
    ]
}
```

And I loop through the array:

```js
data.points.forEach((formData: IAddress) => {
  control.push(this.initiateForm(formData));
});
```

The obtained result is:

```js
{
    location: {
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0 
    },
    name: "Point1",
    pointId: 1
}
```

The desired result is:

```js
{
  latitude: 0,
  longitude: 0  
  name: "Point1",
  pointId: 1
}
```

Just remove location JSON as if to eject longitude and latitude from the location.

Comment: That's not [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), those are objects

Comment: Ok Objects .. results is important :)

Comment: what does this.initiateForm function do

Comment: The syntax is wrong. You can't have `[ prop : { } ]` that doesn't exist.

Comment: _"results is important :)"_ - Important is to _understand_ the stuff you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map`, [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const original = {
    // ...any properties
    // Here, I assume the `points` is an array of objects instead of a buggy array/object
    points: [
      {
        location: {
          latitude: 0,
          longitude: 0 
        },
        name: "Point1",
        pointId: 1
      }
    ]
};

const result = original.points
  .map( ({location, ...rest}) => ({
    ...rest,
    ...location,
  }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a bit of work with `Object.entries`, `Object.fromEntries` and the spread (`...`) operator:

```js
const points =  [{
      location: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0 
      },
      name: "Point1",
      pointId: 1
    }];


const result = points.map(p => {
  return {
    ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(p).filter(e =>  e[0] != "location")),
    ...p.location
  };
});
console.log(result)
```

Comment: this is got me error Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.ts(2339)

Comment: @MichaelTomas `Object.fromEntries` is standard javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

Answer (score 0):

### Flatten for objects

you want something like flatten but on object, so quickly I made some code do it.

without specifing the key (using typeof), but only one level object.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "location": {
      "latitude": 0,
      "longitude": 0
    },
    "name": "Point1",
    "pointId": 1,
    "extraObject": {
      "one": "value1",
      "two": "value2"
    }
  },
  {
    "location": {
      "latitude": 0,
      "longitude": 0
    },
    "name": "Point1",
    "pointId": 1
  }
]


const newArr = arr.map(item => {
  return Object.keys(item).reduce((acc, key) => {
    if (typeof item[key] === 'object') {
      acc = {...acc, ...item[key]};
    } else {
      acc[key] = item[key];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
})

console.log(newArr);
```